# Is it possible to train Neural Network with low amount of instances?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, xgboost

I have faced some problem when I needed to solve Regression Task and use as minimum instances as possible. When I tried to use Xgboost I had to feed 4 instances to get the reasonable result. But Multilayer Perceptron tuned to overcoming Regression problems has to take 20 instances, tried to change amount of neurons&layers but the answer is still 20 .Is it possible to do something to make Neural Network solve Resgression tasks with from 2 to 4 instances? if yes - explain please what should I do to succeed in it? Maybe there is some correlation between how much instances are needed to train and get reasonable results from Perceptron and how features are valuable inside dataset?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: By "instances" do you mean number of training samples? Because in that case 2-4 samples is basically nothing for all but the most trivial of tasks.

Comment: Yes, I mean number of training samples. I understand, but for super trivial tasks it still works fine

Answer (score 1):

With small numbers of samples, there are likely better methods to apply, Xgaboost definitely comes to mind as a method that does quite well at avoiding overfitting.

Neural networks tend to work well with larger numbers of samples. They often over fit to small datasets and underperform other algorithms.

There is, however, an active area of research in semi-supervised techniques using neural networks with large datasets of unlabeled data and small datasets of labeled samples.

Here's a paper to start you down that path, search on 'semi supervised learning'.

http://vdel.me.cmu.edu/publications/2011cgev/paper.pdf

Another area of interest to reduce overfitting in smaller datasets is in multi-task learning.

http://ruder.io/multi-task/

Multi task learning requires the network to achieve multiple target goals for a given input. Adding more requirements tends to reduce the space of solutions that the network can converge on and often achieves better results because of it. To say that differently: when multiple objectives are defined, the parameters necessary to do well at one task are often beneficial for the other task and vice versa.

Lastly, another area of open research is GANs and how they might be used in semi-supervised learning. No papers pop to the forefront of my mind on the subject just now, so I'll leave this mention as a footnote.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, that's exactly what I wanted to see and read.